# TestComplete: errors initializating objects (find, wait)

Tags: java, netbeans, jscript, testcomplete

I am testing java-application based on NetBeans platform.
In TestComplete i use JScript.

To inizialize objects i use function:

```
      function findObj(variable, property) 
  {
    var mainObj = Sys.WaitProcess("javaw", 20000);
      if (mainObj.Exists) {
          var resultObj = mainObj.FindChild(variable, property, 30); 
          if (resultObj.Exists) {
              if (resultObj.WaitProperty("Enabled", true, 20000)) 
                  return resultObj;
              else 
                  Log.Error("Object found, but Enabled didn't become true"); //error 1                
          } else {
              Log.Error("Object not found, see additional info", "Variables: " + variable.toString() + "\nProperty: " + property.toString()); //error 2
          }
      } else {
          Log.Error("Javaw process not found"); //error 3
      }
    return null;
  }
```

I know exactly, that the looking object exists, but sometimes function returns error 2, sometimes error 1. 
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: How exactly is this related to Java?

Comment: I am testing java-application. The code you see is JScript, it is in IDE Testcomplete. Creating this topic, i puted tag Testcomplete first. Sorry, if java tag is wrong

Comment: Why would you use JScript in a Java application? What exactly are you trying to do? have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: TestComplete is platform for creating automated tests (it's good for desctop apps  - Net, Java etc.). It has IDE with 4-5 languages, i choosed JScript. If interested, you can read http://smartbear.com/product/testcomplete/overview/